# How can I use custom grammar with the ast-grep Python API?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, ast-grep

I am currently using the python API for ast-grep to do some automated code cleanup.

I have also managed to get some custom grammar rules compiled and working with the ast-grep CLI (following https://ast-grep.github.io/advanced/custom-language.html).

Is it possible to use my custom language grammar with the python API? I can't see anywhere where I could do the equivalent of defining the custom language and .so file in the sgroot.yaml but using the python API

Tried having the custom language .so file and sgroot.yaml config in the same directory as the python code I want to use it in